# How to use the new functions of PDE toolbox in image processing (Matlab R2015a)

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, matlab-guide

I want to use the line new command of PDE toolbox as Matlab R2015 to restore a noisy image with gaussian noise.

The PDE is:

*∇*.(( *∇*u)/(√(1+|*∇*u|<sup>2</sup>))) +(*f*<sup>2</sup>)/(*u*<sup>2</sup>) = 1 in Ω (*∂*u)/(*∂*n)=0 in *∂*Ω

Where *f* is the noisy image and *u* the restored image.

I tried the following code:

```
clear 
close all
clc

img = 'AA.jpg';
mInputImage = double(imread(img));
mInputImage = rgb2gray(mInputImage);
[numRows, numCols] = size(mInputImage);

Var = 0.04;
Mean = 0;
mInputImageNoisy = imnoise((mInputImage(:,:,1)),'gaussian',Mean, Var); 

% reshape the input and noisy images to vectors
mInputImageVector = reshape(mInputImage,numRows*numCols,1);
mInputImageNoisyVector = reshape(mInputImageNoisy,numRows*numCols,1);

Residu1 = norm(mInputImageVector-mInputImageNoisyVector)/norm(mInputImageVector)

RegularisationCoefficient = 0.7*ones((numRows-1)*(numCols-1),1);
mOutputImageVector = mInputImageNoisyVector;
%a = (mInputImageNoisyVector.^2) ./ mOutputImageVector.^3;
f = 1;
rtol = 1e-1;
c = '1./sqrt(1+ux.^2+uy.^2)';

% Create a PDE Model with a single dependent variable
numberOfPDE = 1;
pdem = createpde(numberOfPDE);

g = @squareg;
geometryFromEdges(pdem,g);

% Plot the geometry and display the edge labels for use in the boundary
% condition definition.
figure;
pdegplot(pdem, 'edgeLabels', 'on');
%axis([0 numRows 0 numCols]);
axis([-2 2 -2 2]);
title 'Geometry With Edge Labels Displayed'


b2 = applyBoundaryCondition(pdem,'Edge',[1 2 3 4], 'u', 0);

[p,e,t] = poimesh(g,numRows, numCols);
numCols
pdemesh(p,e,t);
axis equal

for iter = 1: numRows*numRows,
mOutputImageVector(iter) = pdenonlin(pdem,c,...
     (mInputImageNoisyVector(iter).^2) ./ mOutputImageVector(iter).^3,...
              f,'tol',rtol);
SaveImageVector(iter) = mOutputImageVector;
end

mOutputImage = reshape(SaveImageVector,numRows,numRows);

mOutputImage = uint8(mOutputImage);

figure()
imshow(mOutputImage)
```

Comment: The site has no TeX support, I recommend you to to get some images of the equations here: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: I get this response 
"you need at least 10 reputation to post images"
But my question is posted [her](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358720/how-to-use-the-new-functions-of-pde-toolbox-in-image-processing-matlab-r2015a?noredirect=1#comment2763335_1358720)

Comment: Put a link to the images and someone will put them

Comment: The PDE in Latex langage in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cg6hddi5lxbmf5g/Problem.PNG?dl=0)